# Set column width for Q-column in tabularray

Tags: tabularray, column-width

I have some Q-column but using a `\TblrNote` seems to break the auto-width of those columns...
How can I re-adjust the width so columns 3-8 are of equal width?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray,xcolor,hyperref}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\NewTblrTheme{mytheme}{
  \DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{Continued on next page ...}
  \DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{(Continued)}
  \SetTblrStyle{head}{%
    fg=black}
  \SetTblrInner{%
    row{odd} = {bg=rwthBlueLight},
    row{1}={bg=blue,fg=white,font=\bfseries},
    width = \linewidth,
    hline{1,Z} = {2pt,fg=blue}, % toprule and bottomrule
    hline{2} = {1pt,fg=blue}, % midrule
    }
  }


  \hypersetup{%
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor = blue
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}[%
  theme=mytheme,
  long,
  note{a}={Figures in EUR},
  note{b}={Not all figures in EUR},
  ]{%
    colspec = {X[2,m]X[6,m]*{2}{Q[c]}Q[c]*{3}{Q[c]}},
    cell{1}{1-8} = {cmd={\hypersetup{linkcolor=white}}},
    rowhead = 1
  }
  {Project} %
  & Species %
  & {{{Quantity}}}
  & {{{Average\\ number of\\ weeks kept}}}
  & {{{Housing costs\\ per animal\\ per week}}}\TblrNote{a}
  & {{{Purchasing\\ costs \\per animal}}}\TblrNote{a}
  & {{{Requested\\funds}}}\TblrNote{a}
  & {{{Existing\\funds}}}\TblrNote{a}\\
  Hello & World & 123 & 45.6 & 789 & 10992.0 & 11223.5 & 32012.2\\
  \end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to manually set the width of the columns, you can do so right in the colspec, e.g. `Q[c,2cm]`; otherwise you're probably better off changing them to `X` with an appropriate coefficient. I think you can also do `column{3-8} = {2cm,c}` as another option; but I'm not 100% sure that's what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Your MWE contain errors (color names).
- Added is use of `siunitx` columns.
- Interchanged are Q and X columns ...
- for column headers I would use `\small\bfseries` font size

**Edit:**

- We should be aware, that tags in `TblrNote` are in case of use `hyperref` package are defined by it. That tags in `TblrNote` will be visible, it is need to locally changed `hyperref` setup so, that color of tags will be the same as color of text in rows.
- Since in table is used `siunitx` packages, the column headers should be in parenthesis. That hyper links will work `\TblrNote` had to be outside of them:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4}
\usepackage{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{%
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor = blue % color is the same as the first row color!
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[%
  note{a}={Figures in EUR},
  note{b}={Not all figures in EUR},
                ]{%
    colsep  = 2pt,
    colspec = {*{2}{Q[l]} 
               *{3}{X[c, si={table-format=3.1}]}
               *{2}{X[1.1, c, si={table-format=5.1}]}
                    X[0.8, c, si={table-format=5.1}]
               },
    row{odd} = {bg=LightBlue},
    row{1}   = {bg=blue, fg=white, font=\small\bfseries,
                cmd={\hypersetup{linkcolor=white}} % needed that `TblrNote` tag  become visible
                },
    rowhead  = 1
                }
    \toprule[blue]
Project 
    & Species 
        & {{{Quantity}}}
            & {{{Average number of weeks kept}}}
                & {{{Housing costs per animal per week}}}\TblrNote{a}
                    & {{{Purchasing costs per animal}}}\TblrNote{a}
                        & {{{Requested funds}}}\TblrNote{a}
                            & {{{Existing funds\TblrNote{a}}}} \\
    \midrule[blue]
Hello & World & 123 & 45.6 & 789 & 10992.0 & 11223.5 & 32012.2  \\
Hello & World & 456 & 78.9 & 123 & 10992.0 &  6789.0 &  1234.5  \\
Hello & World & 123 & 45.6 & 789 & 10992.0 & 11223.5 & 32012.2  \\
Hello & World & 456 & 78.9 & 123 & 10992.0 &  6789.0 &  1234.5  \\
    \bottomrule[blue]
  \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
With `tabularray` package version newer than 2022A the table code can be a bit simpler:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4}
\usepackage{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{%
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor = blue % color is the same as the first row color!
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[%
  note{a}={Figures in EUR},
  note{b}={Not all figures in EUR},
                ]{%
    colsep  = 2pt,
    colspec = {*{2}{Q[l]}
               *{3}{X[c, si={table-format=3.1}]}
               *{2}{X[1.1, c, si={table-format=5.1}]}
                    X[0.8, c, si={table-format=5.1}]
               },
    row{odd} = {bg=LightBlue},
    row{1}   = {guard,    % <---
                font=\small\bfseries,
                fg=white, bg=blue,
                cmd={\hypersetup{linkcolor = white}}, % needed that `TblrNote` tag  be visible
                },
    rowhead  = 1
                }
    \toprule[blue]
Project
    & Species  % <---
        &   Qnty  % <--- 
            &   Average number of weeks kept  % <--- 
                &   Housing costs per animal per week\TblrNote{a}  % <---
                    &   Purchasing costs per animal\TblrNote{a}  % <---
                        &   Requested funds\TblrNote{a}  % <---
                            &   Existing funds\TblrNote{a}  % <---  \\
    \midrule[blue]
Hello & World & 123 & 45.6 & 789 & 10992.0 & 11223.5 & 32012.2  \\
Hello & World & 456 & 78.9 & 123 & 10992.0 &  6789.0 &  1234.5  \\
Hello & World & 123 & 45.6 & 789 & 10992.0 & 11223.5 & 32012.2  \\
Hello & World & 456 & 78.9 & 123 & 10992.0 &  6789.0 &  1234.5  \\
    \bottomrule[blue]
  \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Compilation result is the same as before.

Comment: Thank you. But changing the position of `\TblrNote` into `{{{}}}` will not print them.

Comment: @LukasCB, they are there, but it has the same color as row background, so they are not visible. I will look how to change their color.

Comment: Thx for the support: It seems like it would work with `cell{1}{1-8} = {cmd={\hypersetup{linkcolor=white}}},`, to change the linking color locally...

Comment: @LukasCB, you are right.  And this works if `\TblrNote` is out of curly braces. I will add addendum to my answer ASAP

Comment: @LukasCB, see edited answer. Hopefully now works as you desired.

Comment: yes thank you, perfect